# create an array with values located in the array in a key

Tags: key

After running it appears to fail at test: "should return an array containing all the elements greater than 10 in the array located at key". I don't see why.

```js
var obj = {
   key:[1,20,30]
};

function getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  
   var arr = [];
   for (var prop in obj) {
     for (var i = 0; i < obj[prop].length; i++) {
       if (obj[prop][i] > 10) {
         arr.push(obj[prop][i]);
       }
     }
   }
   return arr;
}

getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj,'key')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `key` parameter passed to the function at all, and your `for (var prop in obj)` iteration is unnecessary, as now you are returning an array of all elements over 10 in all properties of `obj`, not just the one specified by `key`. You need to remove that loop and use `key` instead of `prop`:

```js
function getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
    if (obj[key][i] > 10) {
      arr.push(obj[key][i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```